# gVim window gets automatically closed after a few seconds

Tags: windows-7, malware

Whenever I open a gVim instance, the window gets automatically closed after a few seconds. Also, there is a red border drawn around the window.

This happens only with gVim, interestingly. Also, when I open gVim right after a restart it doesn't get closed automatically.

This is very weird. I don't know where should I look into to find the cause of the problem. Do you have any suggestions?

I use windows 7 with gVim 7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same behavior on WinXP when launching some multimedia apps. In my case, it turned out to be a recently updated *Avast v7.0 auto-sandbox* feature.

Comment: Thank you. Probably this is the cause of my case as well. I use Avast as well. Restoring the system to the previous state solved the problem.